# Modify scope variables outside the controller

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

Is it possible to modify `$scope` variables  on button click if the button is outside the controller area?

For example:

```
<input type="button>
<div ng-controller="MeetingsCtrl">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using classes or IDs to find elements is not how things are typically done in Angular.

A controller is typically defined on the top-level element of each view.  If your button belongs to the view managed by `MeetingsCtrl`, it should be inside the `div`.
However, maybe your button is actually part of another view, in which case you need two views to interact with each other.  This is normally done via services, with each controller injecting the same service.  Or you could use events.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. What you have to do is, create different class/id for both input and div tags.

Then make your div as absolute and input as relative. Problem solved!